# "Invalid usage of the option NEXT in the FETCH statement."

Tags: c#, sql, sqlexception

I'm not a SQL master so I'm hoping this isn't too big of an issue. :) Here's my SQL:

```
query = "SELECT id, email, firstName, lastName " +
        "FROM [WarehouseUser] " +
        "WHERE email LIKE '%' + @Filter + '%' OR FirstName LIKE '%' + @Filter + '%' OR LastName LIKE '%' + @Filter + '%'" +
        "ORDER BY " + "DESC" +
        "OFFSET @Offset ROWS " +
        "FETCH NEXT @Length ROWS ONLY;";
```

When this is executed I get the following error:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Incorrect syntax near '@Offset'. Invalid usage of the option NEXT in the FETCH statement.'

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: (1) What database are you using?  Please tag appropriately.  (2) What does the query look like after variable substitution?

Comment: what `sort` contains ? Print somewhere the final sql rendered string, try to direct run it and see where is the issue... I think must be on the `sort` or on the numbers of the offset, length (and before the order you do not have any space.

Comment: it might be the `+` and `"` after the `sort` thats messed up

Comment: This is *exactly* the syntax error you would get if `sort` is empty. From this I tentatively deduce that `sort` is empty.

Comment: Thank you @JeroenMostert and @Aristos for your comments, I'm very new to SQL and appreciate the help. `sort` was empty, but I still get the same error when I set it to `ASC` or `DESC`.

Comment: @Alam I've removed them and nothing changes. Updating code in question.

Comment: That's because `ORDER BY DESC` isn't valid either. You're missing a column for your `ORDER BY` (`ORDER BY WidgetCount DESC`). When constructing dynamic SQL, print it before executing, then use SSMS or Visual Studio's server feature to see if the statement is syntactically legal. With any luck you'll immediately get squigglies telling you it's not. (Also, a basic working knowledge of SQL is highly recommended when you're dynamically cobbling together statements -- you should at least know how [`ORDER BY`](https://docs.microsoft.com/sql/t-sql/queries/select-order-by-clause-transact-sql) works.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can see the problem when you output the value of your variable and look at the SQL Query it writes. Here you need a space after `"DESC"`. Like `"DESC "`. You Currently are having `DESCOFFSET` instead of `DESC OFFSET`. See it here:

http://rextester.com/live/RKRXM8567